# Efficiently sampling from Markov Chain with low-probability transitions

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

I need to sample a large number of paths from a Markov Chain with known state transition matrix $T$, where some of the state transitions are low probability (~0.01%). For example, I might have a large collection of products that can migrate through various states, including to a low probability failure state. By repeatedly simulating a path for each product I can characterize the number of failures across the whole collection, as well as other sample statistics (as I've described it I wouldn't need to use simulation, but the real situation is a little more involved).

Because some of the simulations are very low probability, I need to generate a very large number of paths to come up with a stable answer. I wonder if there are any typical ways of making this more computational efficient, for example somehow oversampling the low-probability events and then re-weighting them later.

Comment: The nature of the low probabilities might influence your choices.  For instance, if most of the states in your system make transitions to themselves with high probabilities, then there are some simple (obvious) approaches, whereas if you have a large number of states and (therefore) most transitions *must* have low probabilities, it's not clear you can do anything at all.  Whatever details of that nature you can add to this post could be helpful.

Comment: @whuber - Most states make transitions to themselves with relatively high probability, although all the off-diagonal cells have some non-zero value.